# Error: error class interface or enum expected in Java class

Tags: java, curly-braces

Unfortunately, I believe I know the issue - I have a brace out of line, but I look through my code and it all seems to be in working order -  I've pored over it line by line and cannot find what could be cause this error (I get 19 of them when I run the code as is). Can anyone provide any help? Is there something else I'm missing here? Thank you in advance. Here is my code:

```
public class DateGenerator
{

    private int month, day;
    private String newDate;
    private String[] monthNames = new String[12];
    private String[] dayNames = new String[7];

    public DateGenerator()
    {
        monthNames = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sept","Oct","Nov","Dec"};

        dayNames = {"Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thur", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"};

        month = 1;
    }


    public void setMonth(int m)
    {
        month = m;
        //System.out.println("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXSETMONTH IS: " + month);
        calculate();
    }

    public String getRandomDate()
    {
        return newDate;
    }

    private void calculate()
    {
        switch(month)
        {
            case 2: //Feb 1-28 
            day = (int)(Math.random()*28);
            //System.out.println("MADE IT HERE1 and day is " + day);
            break;

            case 4: case 6: case 9: case 11:
            day = (int)(Math.random()*30);
            //System.out.println("MADE IT HERE2 and day is " + day);
            break;

            default:
            day = (int)(Math.random()*31);
            //System.out.println("MADE IT HERE3 and day is " + day);
            break;
        }
        if(day == 0) day = 1;
        int dayn = (int)(Math.random()*7);
        //System.out.println("Dayn is " + dayn); 
        newDate = dayNames[dayn] + ", " + monthNames[month]+ "  " + day;
        //System.out.println(newDate);
    }  

}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone! Got it working with your help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with your array initializers.

Instead of:

```
   dayNames = {"Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thur", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"};
```

You should have:

```
   dayNames = new String[]{"Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thur", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"};
```

And the same for `monthNames`.

The way you set these arrays would only work at declaration time. Assuming you need to set them in the class's constructor, they cannot be set that way.

And

```
private String[] monthNames = new String[12];
private String[] dayNames = new String[7];
```

can be replaced by:

```
private String[] monthNames;
private String[] dayNames;
```

unless you have another constructor that doesn't set them in the future.
This is to avoid a useless allocation as each of these fields receive a new array created in the constructor anyway.

Comment: First I thought you were wrong but in fact, thats true. But the initializer without `new String[]` can be used when the initialization is done on the declaration line as @Shivam suggests

Comment: @Stephan Yes it could be done that way as well. This is why I'm saying "assuming you need to set them in the constructor". If for example they are translated later on depending on a Locale passed by parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your initialization to this:

```
private int month = 1, day;
private String newDate;
private String[] monthNames = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sept","Oct","Nov","Dec"};
private String[] dayNames = {"Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thur", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"};
```

Because this are Array Constants and must be initialised at the time of declaration. Also there is no need to have a default constructor, because a class not having a constructor calls default constructor only. So remove it to reduce extra coding.

Comment: Your fix will work, but the reason that you give doesn't make sense. "Because this are Array Constants and must be initialised at the time of declaration." is not true, these are are not constants - you can change the array anytime you like.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt the compiler gives error like this; "Array constants can only be used in initializers" I don't think that I was wrong.

Comment: The initializer is the entire statement. The array constant is the RHS. The thing being initialized is the LHS. Therefore, the array constant is not being initialized.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues i see here..

1. The index of arrays start from 0 and you have your month and day variables starting from 1 and not 0.
2. You have creating a String array but then you are changing your reference Shlublu has explained this and suggested a correct answer.

   ```
       private String[] monthNames = new String[12];
           private String[] dayNames = new String[7];

           public DateGenerator()
           {
               monthNames = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sept","Oct","Nov","Dec"};

               dayNames = {"Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thur", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"};

               month = 1;
           }
   ```